# My question is how to deploy a hyperledger fabric blockchain to kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric

I want to setup my hyperledger blockchain application into kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to encourage questions like this but here are some steps that you could possibly help you:

1. Ensure your application runs correctly locally on Docker.
2. Construct your Kubernetes configuration files. What you will need:

   - A deployment or a statefulset for each of your peers.
   - A statefulset for the couchdb for each of your peers.
   - A deployment or a statefulset for each of your orderers.
   - One service per peer, orderer and couchdb (to allow them to communicate).
   - A job that creates and joins the channels.
   - A job that installs and instantiates the chaincode.
   - Generated crypto-material and network-artifacts.
   - Kubernetes Secrets or persistent volumes that hold your crypto-material and network-artifacts.
   - An image of your dockerized application (I assume you have some sort of server using an SDK to communicate with the peers) uploaded on a container registry.
   - A deployment that uses that image and a service for your application.
3. Create a Kubernetes cluster either locally or on a cloud provider and install the kubectl CLI on your computer.
4. Apply (e.g. kubectl apply -f peerDeployment.yaml) the configuration files on your cluster with this order:

   - Secrets
   - Peers, couchdb's, orderers (deployments, statefulsets and services)
   - Create channel jobs
   - Join channel jobs
   - Install and instantiate chaincode job
   - Your application's deployment and service

If everything was configured correctly, you should have a running HLF platform in your Kubernetes cluster. It goes without saying that you have to research each step to understand what you need to do. And to experiment, a lot.